# Interview question

Tags: university, academic-life, interview

I have a question regarding an interview at a university. The candidates are asked to prepare a presentation on the topic of 'How will you contribute to the teaching, learning, and research in the computer science department.' I have to make a presentation. I need help regarding what content should be in all three parts. should I include the courses that I can teach in 'teaching contribution'. my current and future research endeavors in 'research contribution' . but I really dnt know what should be in the 'learning contribution' part?

Comment: You should get some formal training in the area of teaching and learning so you know how to do this.  A Stack Exchange answer is not sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

I’m only a Master’s student, so I don’t have any firsthand experience with teaching at a tertiary level, but I have done a course on teaching at a secondary (high school) level, and the impression I got from that was that the phrase “teaching and learning” is often used as a single unit.

Presumably, this is because even if you cover all the course material in your teaching, that’s no guarantee that your students actually learned anything!

Comment: +1. Teaching isn't about _covering_ the material. The material is already available to the students in all but advanced graduate courses.